# Java Spring application working on one system, dying on almost identical one

Tags: tomcat, rhel6, springframework, java

### Introduction

I'm running a third party Java Spring application on RHEL, that refuses to run on machines cloned from a certain RHEL 6.5 template. It just dies on startup with a bogus exception (see below).

The versions of the software in question:

```
RHEL 6.5 
Tomcat 7.0.41 (rolled our own, almost vanilla)
Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE (shipped with application)
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
SELinux Status: Permissive
```

I've changed class names to protect the innocent, I highly doubt that the actual software is significant.

Copying tomcat and the instance directory from the broken box to my Linux desktop as is and just running it *works*.

While the setup I am describing is considered a test environment, I did experience this problem on our prod box, which I had to install cleanly from DVD to make the issue disappear. The mentioned setup is the one I re-encountered the problem during puppet module development and managed to conserve and reproduce this problem in.

### Setup

DBs the application uses are kept local (h2) and are set up in tomcat's `server.xml`.

2 RHEL 6.5 templates, both setup for vagrant.

- Broken template: minimal install straight from DVD. Manual setup steps taken to set up template for puppet autosigning, and vagrant template checklist steps.
- Working template: Kickstart minimal setup from DVD, Vagrant/VirtualBox customization via Shellscripts (done with `packer`)

1 box from each template is set up via `vagrant`, both apply the exact same puppet catalog from our puppet master.

### Problem

The application dies on startup in the broken template with this exception:

```
[17.09.2014 19:34:00,290] ERROR                  ContextLoader ( 318) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soaFormFolderService' defined in file [/var/www/apps/content/tomcat/afs-forms/webapps/formserver/WEB-INF/classes/com/aforms2web/afs/formserver/service/
SoaFormFolderService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.corp.Application.getMessageSource(Application.java:234)
        at com.corp.FooService.<clinit>(FooService.java:23)
        ... 33 more
```

The code in question looks like this:

**com.corp.FooService**

```
@Service
public class FooService
{
  protected static MessageSource messageSource = Application.getInstance().getMessageSource();
```

**com.corp.Application**

```
public class Application
{
  private static Application instance = null;

  public static Application getInstance()
  {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Application();
    }
    return instance;
  }
  [...]
  public MessageSource getMessageSource()
  {
    return ((MessageSource)this.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource", MessageSource.class));
  }
```

It runs without a hitch in the second box.

What could cause this to happen?

### Investigation status

diff style `yum list installed` output:

```
--- pkgs.broken
+++ pkgs       
-b43-openfwwf.noarch-5.2-4.el6
-dkms.noarch-2.2.0.3-25.el6
-efibootmgr.x86_64-0.5.4-11.el6
+gcc-c++.x86_64-4.4.7-4.el6
-kernel-devel.x86_64-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6
+kernel-devel.x86_64-2.6.32-431.el6
-kernel.x86_64-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6
+libstdc++-devel.x86_64-4.4.7-4.el6
-puppet.noarch-3.7.0-1.el6
+puppet.noarch-3.7.1-1.el6
```

I compared the systems with rsync (from the working one):

```
rsync \
   --checksum -ani \
   --exclude log \
   --exclude /vagrant \
   --exclude /root \
   --exclude /proc \
   --exclude /sys \
   --exclude /selinux \
   --exclude /dev \
   --exclude /lib/modules \
   --exclude /usr/src \
   --exclude /boot \
   --delete / \
   root@broken:/ \
| grep -ve "^." \
| grep -vEie "puppet|vbox|virtualbox|var/lib/yum|/var/run|sss|var/lib/rpm|logs"
```

See results here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8367930/

I can't figure out what of the changes that popped up might have an impact on a Java Spring application.

**edit**: Glimpse at the offending code added.

Comment: What does the code look like at `someClass.java:234` where the Null exception is thrown? Is it trying to get outside data?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Check the database listener, check the database user and if it has permission on the same tables as in the other host.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixed up static and runtime contexts: method getMessageSource called during this initialization static variables. But the applicationContext is initialized after that. That's why you get NPE - applicationContext is not yet initialized.